# Razor Url link format is not quite right

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to make a link for the user searching my database, and I put the following script on my index page so that I can use Razor with it.
The user types in a textbox which runs this piece of code.  (Called from my .js file)

```
<script>
    function search(query) {
        let url = '@Url.Action("Cars", "Index", new { query = "__query__" })';
        url = url.replace('__query__', query);
        console.log(url);
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

Problem is that the url it goes to is
http://localhost:57719/Index/Cars?query=test

And where I want it to go is
http://localhost:57719/Cars/test

In my controller I use custom routes, like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Cars/{Query}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string Query = null)
    {
        ...
    }
```

How can I format the link so that it goes where I want it to go?

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code:

```
let url = '@Url.Action("Cars", "Index")'; // remove the new { query = "__query__" }
url = url + query; //Just need to concatenate
```

Comment: Then just add the forward slash when concatenating the string. That should be an easy fix. The goal is to produce something like this:

Comment: localhost:57719/Index/Cars/test

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Looking at the urls generated after the Razor Url.Action I could just replace the whole thing after the "?"

Not the most elegant solution, but doing its job.

```
<script>
    function search(query) {
        let url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Cars", new { query = "__query__" })';
        console.log(url);
        url = url.replace('?query=__query__', '/' + query);
        console.log(url);
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

Also

I changed the

```
[Route("Cars/{Query}")]
```

to

```
[Route("~/Cars/{Query}")]
```

In my controller, which seemed to help